# How to configure Hibernate mapping properties in Spring's applicationContext.xml?

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate

I need to enable support of [Joda-Time-Hibernate](http://www.joda.org/joda-time-hibernate/userguide.html) for my application. I use applicatoinContext.xml and Annotations to configure Hibernate.

**applicatoinContext.xml**

```
...
<context:annotation-config/>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
...
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/default" />
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="ee.test.mysql"></property>


        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
          p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">

          </bean>
</beans>
```

Where to add `<property type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime" name="dateTime"/>`? Is there a way to use `applicatioContext.xml`, Annotations and get database properties from `database.properties`?

**UPDATE**

I am using hibernate v4.2.2. What is the best approach to map entities with Joda DateTime to Datetime type of mysql?

**UPDATE2**

Running current configuration results in error:

```
ERROR - Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x16org.joda.time.DateTime\xB8<xdj[\xDD\xF9\x02\x00\x00xr\x00\x1Forg.joda.time.base.BaseDateTime\xFF\xFF\x' for column 'date_time' at row 1
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
```

If my configuration of jodatime is correct for Hibernate 4 then where is the problem? Why `Incorrect datetime value` error appears?

**UPDATE3:**

I kind of kind found get around.

**from main method:**

```
product.setDate_time(new Timestamp((new DateTime(2014,11,11,15,0,0,0)).getMillis()));
```

and changed my **entity** to:

```
private Timestamp dateTimeStart;
```

with no extra type annotations. I am curious, why joda-hibernate and jadira with @Type annotations had not worked in this example.

Comment: Joda-time broke up with hibernate and hibernate is seeing jadira from the time it turned 4, just in case this helps.

Comment: Are you using xml of annotation for mapping properties of entities?

Comment: I guess I am using annotations for properties of entities like that `@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")`

Comment: If you are using `@Type`, you don't need anything else. The property `org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime` is only for when you are using XML to map the entitie's fields

Comment: I have used Jadira and Hibernate with no problems in the past. Just included `org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:2.0.1` in the gradle build file and used `@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")` on each DateTime field.